# TextField not accept text on first click Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

On my first page I have ListView.builder.

```
ListView.builder(
                 itemCount:_docLocatedLot.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) => EditListTile(
                 model: _docLocatedLot[index], onChanged: (ItemsLocatedLot updatedModel) {
                 _docLocatedLot[index] = updatedModel;
            },
         ),
      )
```

Bellow is my source code of EditListTile, after click on edit button and click on TextField new value from keyboard not accept. After click again on TextField (second click) I can enter value in TextField.

How fix this problem?

Where is error in my code? Why I need two click to enter new value?

```
class EditListTile extends StatefulWidget {

  final ItemsLocatedLot model;
  final Function(ItemsLocatedLot listModel) onChanged;
  const EditListTile({super.key, required this.model, required this.onChanged});

  @override
  State<EditListTile> createState() => _EditListTileState();
}

class _EditListTileState extends State<EditListTile> {

  late ItemsLocatedLot model;
  late bool _isEditingMode;

  late  TextEditingController _subTitleEditingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    model = widget.model;
    _isEditingMode = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: titleWidget,
      subtitle: subTitleWidget,
      trailing: tralingButton,
    );
  }

  Widget get titleWidget {
    return Text(
      model.lot
    );
  }

  Widget get subTitleWidget {
    if (_isEditingMode) {
      _subTitleEditingController = TextEditingController(text: model.quantity);
      return TextField(
          controller: _subTitleEditingController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffix: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _subTitleEditingController.text = '';
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.clear,
              ),
            ),
          )
      );
    } else {
      return Text(
        model.quantity.toString();
      );
    }
  }

  Widget get tralingButton {
    if (_isEditingMode) {
      return IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.check),
        onPressed: saveChange,
      );
    } else {
      return IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: _toggleMode,
      );
    }
  }

  void _toggleMode() {
    setState(() {
      _isEditingMode = !_isEditingMode;
    });
  }

  void saveChange() {
    model.quantity = _subTitleEditingController.text;
    _toggleMode();
    widget.onChanged(model);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `InkWell` inside `TextField` ,So

- First Click is consumed by `InkWell`
- Second Click is consumed by `TextField`

#### Problem causing widget

```
TextField
|_ InkWell
```

```
TextField(
          controller: _subTitleEditingController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffix: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _subTitleEditingController.text = '';
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.clear,
              ),
            ),
          )
      );
```

#### Solution

Replace `InkWell` with `IconButton`.

```
TextField(
          controller: _subTitleEditingController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              onTap: () {
                _subTitleEditingController.text = '';
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.clear,
              ),
            ),
          )
      );
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: what use instead InkWell to clear TextField?

Comment: Please find my edited post.

Comment: not working again! Again I must two click to change value inside TextField!

Comment: It totally worked for me !!

Comment: Maybe work if use TextField without ListView, I will check my code again!

Comment: Yes please try to run the code in isolation and try to embed it. You'll know where the error is !, unfortunately i dont have access to the entire code. So i cannot reproduce the code and test in my machine. I can help you in small reproducible logic

Comment: Not working in my example without double click! I will try find some solution. Tnx

Comment: Let me know if there's any way I can help you with . Thank you